# How to add some text after every space with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to transform the following `A0 B7 AA A9 AA FF` into `0xA0 0xB7 0xAA 0xA9 0xAA 0xFF`. I'm trying to achieve this with sed in a script.

I've found how to add `0x` on every line but not at the end of every spaces.

Comment: With an array: `a=(A0 B7 AA A9 AA FF); echo "${a[@]/#/0x}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do:

```
sed -E 's/(\w\w)/0x\1/g' file
0xA0 0xB7 0xAA 0xA9 0xAA 0xFF
```